# Error ante: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php

Llevo trabajando con un miniproyecto para autogestion y me salta el error .Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. y no veo el fallo, al crear registro desde un modal. Pongo el codigo de la consulta, no me deja colgar mucho mas codigo por lo que si hace falta despues cuelgo el del envio de variables.

```
include('../../../app/config.php');

$id_proyecto = $_POST['id_proyecto'];
$nombre_ta = $_POST['nombre_ta'];
$fecha_ta = $_POST['fecha_ta'];
$centro_ta = $_POST['centro_ta'];
$responsable_ta = $_POST['responsable_ta'];
$prioridad_ta = $_POST['prioridad_ta'];
$estado_ta = $_POST['estado_ta'];
$programada_ta = $_POST['programada_ta'];
$detalles_ta = $_POST['detalles_ta'];
$categoria_ta = $_POST['categoria_ta'];
$accionprl_ta = $_POST['accionprl_ta'];


$sentencia = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ag_tareas (id_proyecto, nombre_ta, fecha_ta, centro_ta, responsable_ta, prioridad_ta, estado_ta, programada_ta, detalles_ta, categoria_ta, accionprl_ta) 
VALUES(:id_proyecto, :nombre_ta, :fecha_ta, :centro_ta, :responsable_ta, :prioridad_ta, :estado_ta, :programada_ta, :detalles_ta, :categoria_ta, :accionprl_ta)");

$sentencia->bindParam('id_proyecto', $id_proyecto);    
$sentencia->bindParam('nombre_ta', $nombre_ta);    
$sentencia->bindParam('fecha_ta', $fecha_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('centro_ta', $centro_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('responsable_ta', $responsable_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('prioridad_ta', $prioridad_ta);    
$sentencia->bindParam('estado_ta', $estado_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('programada_ta', $programada_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('detalles_ta', $detalles_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('categoria_ta', $categoria_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam('accionprl_ta', $accionprl_ta);

if ($sentencia->execute()) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['mensaje'] = "Formacion registrada correctamente";
$_SESSION['icono'] = 'success';
header('Location: ' . $URL . '/admin/maestros/centros');
} else {
session_start();
$_SESSION['mensaje'] = "Formacion NO creada";
$_SESSION['icono'] = 'warning';
header('Location: ' . $URL . '/admin/maestros/centros');
}
?>
```

Muchas gracias por adelantado a todos, la verdad es que cuando una empieza sin stackoverflow está perdido.

Comment: Hace tiempo que no uso php pero en la [página del manual de bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php) aparecen los ":" incluidos cuando indicas el nombre del parámetro a sustituir

Answer (score 0):

El problema está porque no pones los ":", cuando hagas el bind param y pongas el identificador del parámetro debes de poner los ":".

El código quedaría así:

```
$sentencia->bindParam(':id_proyecto', $id_proyecto);    
$sentencia->bindParam(':nombre_ta', $nombre_ta);    
$sentencia->bindParam(':fecha_ta', $fecha_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam(':centro_ta', $centro_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam(':responsable_ta', $responsable_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam(':prioridad_ta', $prioridad_ta);    
$sentencia->bindParam(':estado_ta', $estado_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam(':programada_ta', $programada_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam(':detalles_ta', $detalles_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam(':categoria_ta', $categoria_ta);
$sentencia->bindParam(':accionprl_ta', $accionprl_ta);
```